# Swift: How can I catch a modification of a switch from dynamic cell

Tags: swift, dynamic, cell

I need to catch the modification of a switch in a dynamic cell.
The app has dynamic cells to list all BLE devices which where found.

The BLE device should be able to turn on/off via switch.

Now is the problem, I can't catch the switch via Outlet or Action.

How is it possible to catch a change from a dynamic cell.

UI for the problem looks like that:
[UI with dynamic cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiSCq.png)

I found the point where I can catch the tap but there I can't use my methods because in a class type UITableViewCell CoreBluetooth is not supported and I can't fill out the attribute for the CoreBluetooth methods.

```
import UIKit


class remoteCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteCellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteCellImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteCellSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteCellPower: UIProgressView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    //HERE I CAN CATCH THE SWITCH TAP BUT I CAN'T USE CoreBluetooh IN THIS CLASS
    @IBAction func onOff(sender: AnyObject) {


        //OBJECT FROM THE CLASS FOR CONNECT AND SEND TO THE PERIPHERAL
        var connection: ViewController = ViewController()

        connection.viewDidLoad()


        //CANT FILLOUT THE ATTRIBUTES BECAUSE OF MISSING COREBLUETOOTH SUPPORT
    //-->        
        connection.centralManagerDidUpdateState(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>)
        connection.centralManager(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didDiscoverPeripheral: <#T##CBPeripheral#>, advertisementData: <#T##[String : AnyObject]#>, RSSI: <#T##NSNumber#>)
        connection.centralManager(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didConnectPeripheral: <#T##CBPeripheral#>)
        connection.centralManager(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didDiscoverPeripheral: <#T##CBPeripheral#>, advertisementData: <#T##[String : AnyObject]#>, RSSI: <#T##NSNumber#>)
        connection.centralManager(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didConnectPeripheral: <#T##CBPeripheral#>)
        connection.peripheral(<#T##peripheral: CBPeripheral##CBPeripheral#>, didDiscoverServices: <#T##NSError?#>)
        connection.peripheral(<#T##peripheral: CBPeripheral##CBPeripheral#>, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService: <#T##CBService#>, error: <#T##NSError?#>)
        connection.peripheral(<#T##peripheral: CBPeripheral##CBPeripheral#>, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic: <#T##CBCharacteristic#>, error: <#T##NSError?#>)
        connection.peripheral(<#T##peripheral: CBPeripheral##CBPeripheral#>, didWriteValueForDescriptor: <#T##CBDescriptor#>, error: <#T##NSError?#>)

    //->
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    }
```

Comment: show us some of your source code.

Comment: @RAUF have you found the solution?

Comment: I found the point where I can catch the Switch Tap but in the class I can't call the needed methods, because the needed protocol is not supported.
So the solution where I can catch the tap is found but now I have to look how I can switch from this point to an other class to do the CoreBluetooth stuff and jump back to cell class.

Comment: @RAUF check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use Tags to get the switch state. here is the code that i used to get the button click action. Like this

In your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** assign tag to the button.

```
cell.absentButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

In your **button action** get the row of the button

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton {
  if button.selected {
    // set selected
    let row = sender.tag
 }
}
```

From this you can get which switch is changed.